# Keep just letters between two special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, emoji

I try to remove everything except of the letters between the two :

```
text = "nice :star-struck:    :face blowing a kiss: 99"
```

The output should look like this:

Output: `nice :starstruck: :faceblowingakiss: 99`

Is there an easy regex to do this?

EDIT (Thank you Samwise & Andrej Kesely):

```
text = re.sub(
    r"(?<=:[a-zA-Z])(.*?)(?=:)",
    lambda g: "{}".format(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", "", g.group(1))), text
)
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: For the record: I tried with looking ahead for an uneven amount of colons, but I think it's not very efficient: [`re.sub(r'^\s+|[^:A-Za-z]+(?![^:]*(?::[^:]*:[^:]*)*$)|\s+(?=\s|$)',r'',text)`](https://tio.run/##PYzLCoMwFET3fsWtCEl8dNOVAZH@RuuDKGkbbKPcRPrAf09jhW6GmTPDTG97G/XBOfWYRrSAMgisfFkoIAQArXoJ3FiBmbE49wP3EPhFeNx29/Gp9BVEC4MyhkOer234f0C5N3NHkTSVSZZzw4/ZSWSfOqHlzqc6piXnP7MpiyO2@Ckti8osESMpEpKuZywIJlTa0i049wU) For the pattern [see regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/COvALd/1) (it's supposed to also trim spaces from start and end of the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `re`:

```py
import re

text = "nice :star-struck:    :face blowing a kiss: 99"

# remove non-alpha chars inside : :
text = re.sub(
    r":(.*?):",
    lambda g: ":{}:".format(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", "", g.group(1))),
    text,
)

# remove extra spaces
print(" ".join(text.split()))
```

Prints:

```
nice :starstruck: :faceblowingakiss: 99
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `str.split()` and `str.join()`:

```
>>> text = "nice :star-struck: :face blowing a kiss: 99"
>>> ':'.join(
...     ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha()) if i % 2 else s
...     for i, s in enumerate(text.split(":"))
... )
'nice :starstruck: :faceblowingakiss: 99'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension as one liner:

```
>>> " ".join(x for x in "nice :star-struck:     :face blowing a kiss: 99".split(" ") if x.strip())
'nice :star-struck: :face blowing a kiss: 99'
```

Using list comprehension and text in a variable:

```
>>> text="nice :star-struck:     :face blowing a kiss: 99"
>>> text=" ".join(x for x in text.split(" ") if x.strip())
>>> print(text)
nice :star-struck: :face blowing a kiss: 99
```